# Column count not matching value count even though my values match my columns

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

I'm trying to submit a form to my database but my database always returns this error message :

> **Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**

I've looked for solutions for this problem but I just can't manage to find a working one.

This is my code:

```
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["email"]);
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["message"]);

echo "<script>alert('$message $email');</script>";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "INSERT INTO messages (email, message)
VALUES ('$email', '$message');";
```

Comment: Sorry, highlighted code wrong

Comment: Use parameters. Don't munge queries with string values that should be parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use an escape function that requires a connection before connecting; that won't work. Place your connection first, then the rest of your code and then query.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["email"]);
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["message"]);

echo "<script>alert('$message $email');</script>";

$sql = "INSERT INTO messages (email, message)
VALUES ('$email', '$message');";

if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){

    echo "Success";

}else{

    echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Use a prepared statement also:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

and check for errors via PHP with error reporting and make sure all POST arrays have value.

- https://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: This solved two problems for me. I indeed had to put the escape function after the connection, but it still didn't work.

I already had error handling but apparently, the way I did it caused an error too. I swapped my if statement out with yours and it worked.

Thank you.

Comment: @Jojo I've given you methods to check for errors. Use those and report back. Post your db schema and values also. There may be something in there that we need to see.

Comment: @Jojo Or, did what I post solve it? I'm a bit confused. Yet, you're welcome.

Comment: Yes it's working, I couldn't mark your answer as the solution because my question was too recent.

Comment: @Jojo No worries, glad to see everything worked out, *cheers*